# Inverse Fourier Transform of the real part of fourier transform, and inverse transform of the imaginary part of fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier

How can I calculate the inverse fourier transform of the real part of the fourier transformation?

Comment: so, you don't state a question. You just repeated an assignment, as far as I can tell. We can't help you when you're not asking a single, clear, precise question that is based on your own research and allows us to answer clearly and precisely.

Comment: Remember that the Fourier transform, its inverse, the real and the imaginary parts are linear operators. Could you restate that in a more formal shape?